# future tense definition

Tags: tense

does '**future indefinite**' means an action in future which does not have any definite time?

If I say, '**I will come at 10.00 am**.' Is it correct? As I added a time which makes the sentence definite.

**'I will come' or 'I will come at 10'.** Which one is correct according to future indefinite's definition?

Comment: I'm not convinced "future indefinite" is a meaningful concept in English. It definitely isn't something that could be contrasted with "future **definite**", since there's no such thing. Whether or not to include a *time-specific* adverbial element is entirely optional, and doesn't meaningfully affect how we would categoprise the verb usage itself.

Comment: "indefinite future" is not a tense in English. I suggest you google the use of will versus going to and the present continuous to learn about future meanings in English.